# Best RIA tools for a Java backend

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, ria

I've written a java server side application with many classes and EJB's that do things like output RSS information and update a database. I also have a web service connection thorugh SOAP and some basic servlets and xhtml pages that do very simple display of some of the infomration.

What I need now is advice on what a good Java centric approach to building a rich client side experience, and RIA that connected to the server side functionality I've created.

I'm using Glassfish 3.1, and JEE6.  I'm considering Java Server Faces but it's more of a framework for developing simple webpages. What I want is a javascript heavy application that runs in the browser, is very graphical with animations and can connect to the services I've created underneath probably through websockets.

I want all of the AJAX, and Javascript support you would expect from a modern RIA experience.

What Java technologies will get me there. Or am I leaving the Java sphear and entering something else. I'm just trying to stay with java as long as possible for this application as an experiment of Java's abilities. So what Java tools are out there for RIA and integrated JavaScript?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java definitely the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).

You could also look at [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home). Unfortunately there isn't really
a good SOAP client for JavaScript but if you had a JSON REST webservice
and are willing to develop in JavaScript I also recommended
to look at frameworks like [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/), [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/) or [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).

Comment: I don't need a SOAP connection to the RIA I already have that generated from a @webservice annotation of one of my java files on the server. I simply want a way to display and interact with what I've already done graphically and AJAXy

Comment: How do you feel about JSF with PrimeFAces?

Comment: Never liked JSF - always felt messy and backwards for my taste. Don't think that it would be different just because it looks better with PrimeFaces. But try it out and see if you like it.